# WordPress implementation for multiple site in single Linux Server on DMZ

Tags: linux, apache, wordpress

I'm planning to install WordPress on Linux system for my company website, does this scenario works with WordPress?

Single WordPress install but can have multiple domain eg:

www.team1.com
www.team1.com/product2
www.team1.com/product3
www.team2.com
www.team2.com/product2
.
.
.etc

Do I need to perform multiple install of WordPress or Apache can do it for me? How can I set up WordPress for hosting the website in the DMZ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wordpress multisite.  It's available in WP 3+

http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network

Comment: ah so it describes the steps i need to install it ? thanks man.